# Does theory impose a limitation on the size of the sample to be used for measuring permeability?

Tags: continuum-mechanics, transport-phenomena, porous-media

> *Theory imposes no limitation on the size of the sample* to be used ***but***
> it is evident that in order to minimize effects due to local
> inhomogeneities in the material such as concretions, small shale
> streaks, and the like, the sample should be of a generous size. When
> possible they are cut to a cross-sectional area of 5 to 10 cm2 and 1
> cm or more in length although frequently the size is much less because
> of the smallness of the original sample.

(emphasis added).

This is what is said in the American Petroleum Institute's Recommended Practice for the standard procedure for determining permeability of porous media (in the 1st ed. (1935), in the 2nd ed. (1942), and in the 3rd ed. (1952)).

**What is the theory to which this claim is being based on?**

Some thoughts:
There is [Darcy's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darcy%27s_law):
$$Q=\frac{kA}{\mu}\frac{\Delta p}{L}$$
I'm not sure if this equation constitutes a mathematical theory, nor if it is what the author of above statement is referring to. Variables $A$ and $L$ respectively refer to the cross-sectional area of the sample normal to flow and length of the sample parallel to the direction of flow. Typically, samples are made to be right-circular cylinders of diameter $D$ and length $L$. So at the very least $D\gt0$ and $L\gt0$. But then I have read the following:

> Darcy’s Law may be considered to represent the fluid flux at a point
> as long as we remember that it was developed for the laminar
> (streamline) flow of a fluid in a porous medium large enough to
> contain a representative collection of matrix grains and connected
> pores. That is, Darcy’s Law does not apply to the flow of the fluid
> through each individual pore but rather to the rock as a whole as long
> as the rock sample is much larger than the individual pore. Darcy’s
> Law may be thought of as a statistical law which predicts the average
> behavior of a collection of pores within the rock as a whole.

So, it would seem that for a valid permeability $k$ to be measured, it would require the length scale of the sample, $D$ and $L$, to be greater than some minimum length scale that describes a representative collection of matrix grains and connected pores. This would seem to contradict the claim in question, no?

Comment: It is always taken as understood that concepts for describing bulk behaviour will not hold when going into the microscopic, quantum, limit. The quotation of the American Petroleum Institute does not speak of a minimum length scale, but is understood to necessarily have one. It is, instead, trying to assert that there is no maximum length scale.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent (+1). That is a good point. So, the statement is correct, but not technically true? I would think the implied would be that the sample is homogeneous with respect to permeability, and thus there is no limitation on the size, large or small, of the sample, no? I added the remainder of the quote to the post. Based on what is said, it would seem that they were not concerned about a maximum length scale, and in fact encouraged testing with larger size samples. Would you agree?

Comment: the goodness of the kind of geometrical arguments going into that law gets better with size, so of course they encourage for bigger.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent (+1) What are the geometrical arguments?

Comment: Oh, I just mean things like factorising out the lengths, areas, volumes, etc. That is a standard geometrical factorisation argument that is used everywhere in physics and engineering.